# Latex to Word conversion

Tags: conversion, msword

My department expects me to write my masters dissertation in MS Word (which is just silly I know).

I however want to use Latex and then just convert the entire document to word afterwards, as I think the department just wants the word version for it's archive, I doubt if they will mind if I hand in a Latex formatted document as a final submission.

Are there options of converting from Tex to Word?

Comment: Is the department requiring MS Word in part because it has provided a detailed layout and style template for its students' dissertations?

Comment: I wouldn't do this on the basis of merely doubting they will mind your handing in a LaTeX formatted final version. *Check* whether they *will* mind. And if you do this, keep your thesis formatting as simple as possible - as close to the default `book` or `report` class as you can with as few packages and as little custom code as you can manage. That will make conversion as little of a royal pain as possible.